# Elimination of variables the old-fashioned way

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to eliminate variables in some fairly simple sets of equations. A typical example is:

$$ 9 x^2 + 18 xy + 9 y^2 - 32 = 256z$$
$$ 9 x^2 + 6 xy - 3 y^2 - 8 = 376z$$
$$ 9 x^2 - 6 xy  + y^2 = 512z$$

I'd like to eliminate $x$ and $y$. Mathematica tells me that the answer is $ 161 z^2 -162z + 1 = 0 $. OK. Good.

**But how would I do this elimination manually (without Mathematica). I'm hoping that there is some fairly simple mechanical process that I can express in a few hundred lines of C code.**

I realize that general elimination procedures are pretty complex, but this sort of problem looks quite special and therefore easier (I hope). Roughly speaking, it's just a system of "linear" equations in the variables $x^2$, $xy$, $y^2$, and $z$. Is there some sort of diagonalization process that can be applied, for example ?

Edit:
From the proposed answer below, I see that things can be simplified by setting $p=3x+3y$ and $q = 3x-y$. Then the equations become:

$$p^2 = 32 + 256z$$
$$pq = 8 + 376z$$
$$q^2 = 512z$$
I can then eliminate $p$ and $q$. Is there always a linear transformation that simplifies the problem in this way? If there is, how do I compute it?

Comment: If you can diagonalize the problem into something like $u^2 = \lambda_1$, $uv=\lambda_2$ and $v^2=\lambda_3$, then you could use that $u^2v^2 = (uv)^2$, thus $\lambda_1\lambda_3 = \lambda_2^2$.

Comment: Yes. But my remaining question is ... how do I know when this diagonalization is possible, and how do I write code to find it ? Specifically, is it always possible ??

Comment: Are you familiar with Gauss-Jordan elimination? The answer by DonAntonio illustrates how it works. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination)

Comment: I see how Gaussian elimination helps with the "mechanical" approach, but not the clever one. How would it tell me that $p=3x+3y$ and $q=3x-y$ is the magic simplifying change of variables?? I don't think DonAntonio's answer shows that.

Comment: His method reduces the system of equations to a system that will be of the type $1\cdot x^2 + 0\cdot xy + 0\cdot y^2 = f_1(z)$, $xy = f_2(z)$ and $y^2 = f_3(z)$. And then you have that $f_1f_3 = f_2^2$. You don't really need to find that substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use gaussian elimination (or other equivalent methods) to find expressions for $x^2$, $xy$ and $y^2$ in terms of $z$ - treating them as independent variables, and substitute these to get an equation for z. Then you still have to solve for $x$ and $y$.

There is an easier way in this case, but in a general case this makes progress.

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising. I don't really see the "gives a linear equation for z" part, but maybe it will become clear when I work through the details.

Comment: @bubba Deleted linear comment as it is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Mark's idea with the unknowns $\,x^2\,,\,xy\,,\,y^2\,$ , using the augmented matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 9&18&9&\;\;256z+32\\9&6&\!\!\!\!-3&\;\;376z+8\\9&\!\!\!\!-6&1&\;\;512z\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{\begin{cases}R_2-R_1\\R_3-R_1\end{cases}}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 9&18&9&\;\;256z+32\\0&\!\!\!\!-12&\!\!\!\!-6&\;\;120z-24\\0&\!\!\!\!-24&\!\!\!\!-8&\;\;256z\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow$$

$$\stackrel{R_3-2R_2}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 9&18&9&\;\;256z+32\\0&\!\!\!\!-12&\!\!\!\!-6&\;\;120z-24\\0&0&4&\;\;16z+48\end{pmatrix}$$

We get thus

$$\text{From}\,\,R_3\,:\;\;4y^2=16z+48\Longrightarrow y=\pm\sqrt{4z+12}$$

$$\text{From}\,\,R_2\wedge R_3\,\,\text{above}\;\;-12xy-6y^2=120z-24\Longrightarrow $$

$$\pm 2x\sqrt{4z+12}-16z-48=20z-4\Longrightarrow \pm x\sqrt{4z+12}=18z+22\Longrightarrow$$

$$x=\pm\frac{9z+11}{z+3}$$

and etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Clever Observant Solution (as in Mark's comment)**

Denote the right-hand sides by $a$, $b$, $c$. In other words, $a = 32+256z$, $b = 8 + 376z$, $c = 512z$. Also, let $p = 3x + 3y$ and $q = 3x - y$. Then the equations become simply:
$$ p^2 = a \quad ; \quad pq = b \quad ; \quad q^2 = c$$
From this, we get $b^2 - ac = 0$. Substituting for $a$, $b$, $c$ gives us the same result we got from Mathematica: $161z^2 -162z + 1 = 0$.

**Dumb Mechanical Solution (which is what I need)**

Let $M$ be the matrix
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 9&18&9\\9&6&\!\!\!\!-3\\9&\!\!\!\!-6&1\end{pmatrix}$$
and let $u = x^2$, $v = xy$, $w = y^2$. Then the original equations can be written as
$M.[u, v, w]^t = [a, b, c]^t$.

Using standard techniques (eigenvalues or Gaussian elimination), we can find a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}MP = D$. The solution of the system of equations is then $[u, v, w]^t = PD^{-1}P^{-1}[a, b, c]^t$. Setting $v^2 = uw$ again gives us the equation $161z^2 -162z + 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Factorize the left sides to separate x and y, and it's easy later.

Comment: OK. I wrote the first equation using $(3x+3y)^2$ and the third one using $(3x-y)^2$. Sorry to be dense, but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: you can now express x as something else, and put that instead of x in the other equations

Comment: or, another approach, you can multiply the first equation by $A$, the second by $B$, the third by $C$, and make a system of equations, that they must satisfy in order to cancel out $x^2$, $xy$, and $y^2$, but this will work only if you are lucky.

Comment: In this case we get three equations $(3x+3y)^2=A, (3x+3y)(3x-y)=B, (3x-y)^2=C$. This allows us to put AC=B^2 which gives a quadratic equation in $z$.

Comment: @Mark. Thanks. I just realized that, too. But this requires some insight, so I have no idea how to code it. Your other answer looks better (dumber :-))